# login different users from different collections on android studio using firebase firestore auth

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have 2 kinds of users for my android app -User and Donor and they are from different collections.
the problem is when I try to use the email and password of a User for the Donor instead of making a Toast saying "cannot log in" the app just crashes. I tried using .addOnFailureListener here but it doesnt work

anyways here's my code.

```
public class log_in extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText lEmail, lPassword;
    Button btnLogIn;
    Spinner UserDonor;
    FirebaseAuth lFirebaseAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore lFirestoreFirebase;
    String userID, donorID;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activtiy_log_in);

        lEmail = findViewById(R.id.etxtEmailLogIn);
        lPassword = findViewById(R.id.etxtPasswordLogIn);
        UserDonor = findViewById(R.id.spnUserDonor);
        lFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        lFirestoreFirebase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        btnLogIn = findViewById(R.id.btnLogIn);

        
        //button log-in
        btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String Email = lEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String Password = lPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String userDonor = UserDonor.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

                //if User is selected on spinner
                if (userDonor.equals("User")){
                    // authenticate the user
                    lFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                userID = lFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                DocumentReference userRef = lFirestoreFirebase.collection("users").document(userID);
                                userRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                        String usertype;
                                        usertype = documentSnapshot.getString("userType");
                                        if (usertype.equals("user")){
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), main_user.class));
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            Toast.makeText(log_in.this, "no user account is Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            lFirebaseAuth.signOut();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(log_in.this, "cannot login" + task.getException().getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            lFirebaseAuth.signOut();
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(log_in.this, "cannot login" + task.getException().getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                lFirebaseAuth.signOut();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                 //if Donor is selected on spinner
                else if (userDonor.equals("Donor")){
                    // authenticate the donor
                    lFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                donorID = lFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                DocumentReference donorRef = lFirestoreFirebase.collection("donors").document(donorID);
                                donorRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                        String usertype;
                                        usertype = documentSnapshot.getString("userType");
                                        if (usertype.equals("donor")){
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), main_user.class));
                                            Toast.makeText(log_in.this, "donor Logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            Toast.makeText(log_in.this, "no donor account is Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            lFirebaseAuth.signOut();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(log_in.this, "cannot login" + task.getException().getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        lFirebaseAuth.signOut();
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(log_in.this, "cannot log in" + task.getException().getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                lFirebaseAuth.signOut();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }




            }
        });

       

    }
}
```

or is there a better way for this to work?

Comment: Hi Joshua, can you share your logcat related to crash?

Comment: it's a little bit long, here is the uploaded txt file [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/20e4c4c5a5dd18b86d3a4af463c09c7d20220411191219/294371)

Comment: You just need to copy codes that are related only.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond with @AlexMamo